# What are the differences between scm adapter and CCRC eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

Eclipse SCM adapter - spawns another window in order to do operations and not within the IDE?
CCRC - integrated with eclipse, e.g. label decorator can be seen in IDE. It only supports to a specific version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is the type of view (access and visualization mechanism) involved and the presence or absence of ClearCase client installed on the user desktop:

- SCM adapter allows you to used snapshot and dynamic views, with a direct communication between your view server (meaning: full ClearCase client installation) and the VOB server (and its data)
- CCRC is for *web* view, that is snapshot views with a view storage stored on the CCRC server, server which will handle all communication with the VOB server. You communicate with the web view server (the CCRC server) through requests, without having a full ClearCase client installed: it is a WAN-based solution.

The differences in term of features between SCM adapter and CCRC are [listed there](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg21233091) and [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg21233090).

Again:

- The SCM adapater is an eclipse plugin allowing you to exploit the CC client without leaving eclipse.
- the CCRC is a RCP (Rich Client Platform) based on eclipse, replacing a CC client and communicating with a CCRC web view server.

Comment: Yet he cannot be reached and hired

Comment: @MarcH: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/vonc. By looking around a bit, you can join me ;)

Comment: I found a way, but it was really far from obvious